# Recentering divs on window resize gets me "Uncaught TypeErrors"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got a modal window set-up on my page that works fine, but needs repositioning on window resize in order to stay centred. Unfortunately, I simply get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'outerHeight'

Am I using "this" incorrectly?

```
        $(window).resize(function() {
            //If mask is open, resize modal elements
            if ($('#modalMask').is(':visible')) {
                //Resize and position modal windows
                //Get window dimensions
                var mWinHeight = $(window).height();
                var mWinWidth = $(window).width();
                //Make sure all open modal windows are centred
                $('.modalWindow:visible').each(function (i) {
                    var $this = $(this);
                    $this.css('top', mWinHeight/2-(this.outerHeight()/2));
                    $this.css('left', mWinWidth/2-(this.outerWidth()/2));
                });
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forgot some '$':

```
$this.css('top', mWinHeight/2-($this.outerHeight()/2));
$this.css('left', mWinWidth/2-($this.outerWidth()/2));
```

Comment: Happens to everyone. No worries.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if `outerHeight` is a property of a DOMElement but you have to either remove the parenthesis to use the javascript property:

```
this.outerHeight
```

or make a jquery object from `this` to use the .outerHeight() jquery method:

```
$(this).outerHeight()
// or use $this.outerHeight()
```

Comment: Thanks, @sje397 nailed it moments before you - I was missing a $.

Comment: Yep. What matters is that you resolved your issue :o) Up-voting is still an option btw ;-)